# Flickering(Blinking) screen when using Shared elements animation to change between activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm developing an android app and using a shared element transition between the splash screen activity and my login activity. while the transition is happening i get to see the background of my phone, apps and everthing, the only thing that i can see from my application is the logo animation, everything else, gone.

Here is my code:

Splash Screen (Origin)

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/meofat_logo"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/meofat_logo"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
        android:elevation="24dp"
        android:transitionName="logo"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/meofat_tipo"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/meofat_tipo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="24dp"
        android:transitionName="tipo"/>
```

Login Screen (Destination)

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/meofat_logo"
            android:layout_width="58dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/meofat_logo"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:elevation="24dp"
            android:transitionName="logo"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/meofat_tipo"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@drawable/meofat_tipo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="24dp"
            android:transitionName="tipo"/>
```

SplashScreen Code:

```
public class RedirectActivity extends Activity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;
    LinearLayout logo,tipo;
    Animation upToDown;
    Animation downToUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_redirect);

        logo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.meofat_logo);
        tipo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.meofat_tipo);
        upToDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.uptodown);
        logo.setAnimation(upToDown);
        downToUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.downtoup);
        tipo.setAnimation(downToUp);




        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MEOFatSession session = new MEOFatSession(RedirectActivity.this);

                if (session.isLoggedIn()){
                    Intent goToMeasurement = new Intent(RedirectActivity.this,
                            MeasurementActivity.class);
                    RetrofitInitializer.getInstance().addCredentials(session.getCredentials());
                    startActivity(goToMeasurement);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Intent goToLogin = new Intent(RedirectActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(RedirectActivity.this,findViewById(R.id.meofat_logo),
                                    "logo");
                    startActivity(goToLogin,  optionsCompat.toBundle());
                    finish();
                }

            }
        },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);


    }
}
```

A gif trying to illustrate the problem.

https://giphy.com/gifs/d1G6hKgTAsX5hOo0

Comment: pls post the animation xml

Comment: I'm  just using standard "auto" animation for the transition, given the positions in activity 1 and 2. The "topToDown" and "DownToTop" ones are working just fine.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the fact that I'm using linear layout on the logo and tipo and not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the finish() method solved the issue. Apparently it would destroy the activity during the animation causing it to vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Like [@GaboSampaio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113818/flickeringblinking-screen-when-using-shared-elements-animation-to-change-betwe/48402104#48402104) said, `finish()` caused the flickering. You can delay it :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(this::finish, 1000);
```

Comment: Change your name to Life Saver. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent goToLogin = new Intent(RedirectActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);

ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
    RedirectActivity.this,

    // Now we provide a list of Pair items which contain the view we can transitioning
    // from, and the name of the view it is transitioning to, in the launched activity
    new Pair<View, String>(findViewById(R.id.logo_splash),
    "tipo"));

ActivityCompat.startActivity(RedirectActivity.this, intent, activityOptions.toBundle());
```

Comment: The animation per se is working, still have the same problem with your method. While transitioning, everything else vanishes but the logo animation.

Comment: remove  finish();

Comment: alireza silsepor do you mind add that on a separated response so i can vote as the correct answer?